# Display node title in view comment type

Tags: views

I have created a view (using views 2) with type = comment (displaying comments).
Now i can display comment author, comment post date fields, but i can't create a node title field which belongs to comment.

Tried using views customfield, but `$data` variable isn't allowed here, only `$comment` variable. Please throw me in a right directions, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting up a new Relationship within the View.

1. Add a new relationship to "The node the comment is a reply to."
2. Check box that "requires this relationship"
3. You should now be able to add a new field for the node title[image]

Comment: Thanks! saved my time :) Also do you know how to make that node title as link to comment anchor?